# Adding “’s” when the name ends with “s”?

Tags: grammaticality, punctuation

Example 1:

> Peter’s bag

Example 2:

> Chris’s car

Is example 2 correct? If not, what is the rule for names that end with “s”?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example 2 is correct.

The rule differs when dealing with plurals.

> The boys' jackets could not be found.

Comment: The rule differs when dealing with **regular** plurals.

Comment: Actually the rule differs depending on a whole number of factors. There will be circumstances where *Chris's* is plain wrong and you should really go with *Chris'* instead.

Comment: No, I don't think *Chris's* is ever wrong.  Can you present one such circumstance?